# Extract fields from object present in multiple nested levels using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a text file having data records as below:

```
{"input":{"payload":{"id":"rec1","var2":"imp_val1","var3":"","var4":"000000"},"recordName":"typeABC"}}
{"input":{"recordName":"typeBCD","payload":{"var5":"val_var66","recordType":"typeA","id":"rec2","var2":"imp_val2","var3":"","var4":"000000"}}}
{"recordName":"typeEFG","payload":{"var5":"val_var55","recordType":"typeA","id":"rec3","var2":"imp_val3","var3":"","var4":""}}
{"payload":{"id":"rec4","var2":"imp_val4","var3":"","var4":"000000"},"recordName":"typeABC"}
```

There is a recordName and payload key which has my values of interest. Some records are wrapped inside another key input.
What i want to extract is id and var2 from all these records into a new csv file.

I figured if the data format were uniform, i could do:

```
cat file | jq -r "[.payload.id, .payload.var2] | @csv" > newFile
```

OR

```
cat file | jq -r "[.input.payload.id, .input.payload.var2] | @csv" > newFile
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `payload` object is nested in multiple levels in each of the object, you can apply [Recursive Descent `..`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RecursiveDescent:..) and ignore if the key is not present

```
jq -r '..| .payload? // empty | [ .id, .var2 ] | @csv' file
```

<sup>[jqplay - Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/DyCqCde4ok)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

BTW i figured following works too:

```
jq -r 'if .input then .input.payload else .payload end | [.id, .var2] | @csv' file > newFile
```

Comment: Is there a performance difference if I cat the file and then pipe the jq command?

Comment: You'll get an error with this run on an object like `{"input":1}`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I agree. For my specific case, I know that "payload" will always exist and thus my answer.

Comment: Next time include such details in the question, so that we don't have to guess.